# How do I remove red bars in my reputation graph?

Tags: support, reputation, merge-accounts

I want to merge my accounts in Stack Overflow one of my accounts has got red bars like this

[image]

If I merge 2 accounts one with as shown and other without it do these lines disappear?

Does merging accounts delete the red lines (if present in an account)?

Comment: Merging an account merges reputation changes. If the result is still negative for that day the red bar will remain.

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact remove the red bars in your reputation graph by deleting the answer or Question that got down-voted so much. But sometimes you get down-voted for good answers/questions, so you might not want to delete them.

Anyway, you don't have to be mad about a little red bar. ;)

Comment: Sometimes a question you answered gets deleted and you lose all your rep from it. There's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Red lines display negative reputation. At the end of the day, if your reputation is below 0, you have a red bar and if you have a positive reputation, you got a green one displaying your reputation amount earned in that day.

If you merge your accounts, your reputation also gets merged. So your daily reputation is calculated as the total of each day of your merged accounts.

[More information about account merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) can be found here, and for the reputation problem, you must fix what caused you negative reputation (down-voted question and answers, deleted question/answer that had earned you reputation before etc.) You can check [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for details.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you're allowed as many accounts as you like.

Comment: Technically having more than one account *is* allowed. What's not allowed is for those accounts to interact via voting or answering.